# Adobe Edge Firefox iframe error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adobe-edge

I have a animation using Adobe Edge 6.
I'm trying to include the animation inside an `iframe`. The code works well on `Chrome` and `IE 10`. But on Firefox I'm getting a javascript error on Adobe Edge library  `TypeError: C.getComputedStyle(...) is null -> edge.6.0.0.min.js Line-77`.

If I open the animation page on `Firefox 43` it's working well, I'm only getting the error when including the animation inside an `iframe`.

Animation page:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/Scripts/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-1689000111 {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        div {
            position: absolute !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        AdobeEdge.loadComposition('Test', 'EDGE-1689000111', {
            scaleToFit: "both",
            centerStage: "none",
            minW: "0",
            maxW: "undefined",
            width: "870px",
            height: "350px"
        }, { dom: [] }, { dom: [] });
    </script>
    <!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <div id=" stage" class="EDGE-1689000111">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `iframe` using the animation page:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" src="PATH"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue some days ago.
One of the possible reasons is "display:none" rule on the iframe (or one of its parent nodes). This may cause an error even if "display" rule is set to "block" later.

Here is the related issue at bugzilla: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548397

Could you check if the iframe (or its parents) has "display:none" at the time when it first appears in DOM?

Now we are going to set "opacity:0" or "visibility:hidden" instead of "display:none".

Comment: Yes, the parents have the "display:none". This animation is inside a bootstrap tabs.

The workaround I used (comment on Bug 548397):
if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   window.oldGetComputedStyle = window .getComputedStyle;
   window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) {
      var t = window.oldGetComputedStyle(element, pseudoElt);
      if (t === null) {
         return {};
      } else{
         return t;
      }
   };
}

Comment: Sure, this workaround is much better if you could control the iframe code. My suggestion was about cases with external iframe contents (for example, ad banners at the page). Did you find any information about resolving this issue in edge sources? Thank you.

Comment: sadly, I didn't found a better solution